# Why do symbolic functions display as "0" in octave?

Tags: octave, symbolic-math

So, this is my code in a script:

```
f_RI(x, tau, A)=A*heaviside(-x-tau);
pretty(f_RI);
```

it displays this:

```
>> script
0
```

It also doesn't work with `disp(f_RI)`, but it used to work earlier. I can't remember to have changed that part of the code at all. What am I doing so wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason. With `syms x positive`, `f_RI` can only be 0.